# Memory allocation and free

Tags: c, windows, winapi, memory, memory-leaks

Is it possible to allocate 7 bytes of memory and just free the first 3 bytes to form a 4 byte block, through any Windows APIs.

Comment: what for? if you better describe what you want to achieve you would get meaningful answers...

Comment: Why would you do this? Why not just allocate 4 bytes to begin with?

Comment: Do a realloc and let the implementation worry about how it should get you those 4 bytes you need. If you need to be sure (because you need to use the same pointer) implement a memory allocator yourself. PS: I don't think windows offers any mechanism for keeping the pointer. You could always use a length parameter for your 7 byte memory block that tells you how much memory you are "allowed" to use from it.

Comment: AFAIR Windows itself manages memory in blocks of 4K. Lower values are managed by the memory manager of your c compiler.

Comment: I need the allocated memory address as in multiple of 4. My addresses should be like 400, 404,408,40c etc., hence allocating 7 and finding the multiple of 4 in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

But you could very well use memmove and realloc to reduce the amount of memory that is used:

```
memmove(ptr, ptr + 3, 4);
ptr = realloc(ptr, 4)
```

But that's most likely slower than just keeping the memory at its initial size.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `memmove()` to move the last four bytes to the start of the allocated block then use `realloc()` to shrink it down to four bytes.

But why would you ever want to? You can always just have another pointer to the last four bytes of malloced memory like this:

```
typedef unsigned char uint8;

uint8* psevenbytes = (uint8*)malloc(sizeof(uint8) * 7);

if (psevenbytes != NULL)
{
    uint8* pfourbytes = psevenbytes + 3;

    // ... do stuff

   free(psevenbytes);
   psevenbytes = NULL;
}
```

Or you could use a `struct`.

Comment: If i Have another pointer to point the 4th byte and pass on through the program, I am not sure I could release the first 3 bytes as my pointer pointing the 4th byte now.  can you confirm

Comment: @Beetle: That is correct, in that code you must `free` the whole block using the `psevenbytes` pointer. If you want to free part of it you'd have to use `memmove/realloc` as discussed - but why would you need to do this??

Comment: I need the allocated memory address as in multiple of 4. My addresses should be like 400, 404,408,40c etc., hence allocating 7 and finding the multiple of 4 in it. IS there any other way better than this?

Comment: @Beetles: That is a very unusual requirement! Any particular reason? On a 32-bit system the chances are that it will be aligned on a 4-byte boundary. On an embedded system you can usually directly specify the addresses of particular variables. I suggest you post a more general question asking how you force memory allocation on a four-byte boundary and see what answers come up.

Answer (score 2):

No.  The Windows heap allocation APIs are required to return a value which is naturally aligned (in other words, the block address % sizeof(void *) == 0).  For a 32 bit processor that means that every allocation is 4 byte aligned. If there was a way of doing what you want, the newly reallocated block would be aligned on a 3 byte boundary (the initial 7 byte block would be aligned on a 4 byte boundary, adding 3 bytes creates a 3 byte aligned pointer.

As others have suggested, copying the memory down gets you the closest to what you've asked for.  But there will be some performance cost associated with that.